# Tensorflow js installation problem on the raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, npm, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make a node sever run a TensorFlow model on Raspberry Pi I made a simple test on Ubuntu, and it works, but it gives me an error in the raspberry

```
    throw new Error("The Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not " +
          ^

Error: The Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not be found at path: /home/pi/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/lib/napi-v8/tfjs_binding.node. 
Please run command 'npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node --build-addon-from-source' to rebuild the native addon module. 
If you have problem with building the addon module, please check https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-node/WINDOWS_TROUBLESHOOTING.md or file an issue.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/index.js:49:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:199:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:183:25)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (internal/modules/run_main.js:59:12)
```

this is the code I'm trying to run

```
 path='file:///home/sa2/work/models/js_model/model.json';





const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(path);
const sum=model.summary();

const test=[]
const prediction = tf.tidy(()=>{
    // create a tensor from an input 
    const ty = tf.tensor(test).expandDims();
    ;
    
    // insert a dimension into the tensor's shape 
     //const inputTensor = tensor.expandDims();
    
    //execute the infernce for the input tensors

    const tensor = model.predict(ty) ;
    return tensor.dataSync();
})

export const per = prediction;
console.log(sum);
console.log(per) ;
```

I tried uesing

`npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node --build-addon-from-source`

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with trying to run tfjs on the Raspberry Pi's ARM chip. Try the command referenced to have it rebuild the library for the RPi.

```
npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node --build-addon-from-source
```

Comment: I tried, and it gives me this message `rebuilt dependencies successfully` when I run the code again, it gives me the same error